# $\deg(f)\neq 0\Rightarrow f$ is surjective

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I prove the following statement?

> Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map between closed, connected, oriented manifolds of the same dimension. If $\deg(f)\neq 0$, then $f$ is surjective.

Here $\deg(f)$ denotes the [Brower degree of $f$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrouwerDegree.html).

*Note:* This is not homework, but a question that came up while studying for a course of differential geometry. I tried to prove the statement in more than a way, but always noticed that what I did usually led to nowhere. Any hint or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a point not in the image of $f$.  Is that a regular value?

Comment: @RyanBudney Oh right, that's true! Thus $\# f^{-1}(x)=0$ and that would be a contradiction, right? But still there is a detail that bothers me: consider the identity map of the interval $[0,1]$. It has degree $1$. But it is homotopic to a constant map, which should have degree $0$. This would be a contradiction, so where am I doing wrong? Anyway write down your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: You've contradicted your assumption that the manifold is *closed*.  The degree isn't even defined for maps of manifolds with boundary.

Comment: @RyanBudney Ah, I see. Is the problem that you can't show invariance under homotopies, since if $M$ is a manifold *with boundary* then $M\times[0,1]$ is not a manifold? And is the implication $f$ surjective $\rightarrow\deg(f)\neq 0$ true?

Comment: @Daniel:  There are plenty of surjective maps which have $0$ degree.  For example, consider the map of a circle which maps the top half all the way around once and the bottom half arond the opposite way.